# How do I make 2 infinite loops with Await and Async

Tags: asynchronous, async-await

Basically, I have 2 functions

```
Public Async Function finRepeatOrderingAsync() As Task
    basWindowFuncs.SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20()
    Await mainLoopRepeat()
    Await secondaryLoop()
    Do
        Await mainLoopRepeat()
    Loop
End Function
```

Basically, I want mainloopRepeat and secondary loop to repeat again, again, and again.

The problem with this arrangement is that the secondaryLoop never ends and the await ensure that the do loop for the mainLoop is never reached.

What I want is

do mainloopRepeat one time.

Do secondaryLoop infinite number of time.

While secondaryLoop is running loop mainLoopRepeat continuously.

How should I do that?

The secondary loop looks like this

```
Private Async Function secondaryLoop() As Task
    Do
        CoinClass.assertCoinsNameOkay()
        Await CoinClass.checkMarketForAllCoinsAsync()
        CoinClass.assertCoinsNameOkay()
    Loop

End Function
```

I know I can do it like this.

```
Public Async Function finRepeatOrderingAsync() As Task
    basWindowFuncs.SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20()
    Await mainLoopRepeat()
    Dim secondaryLoop1 = secondaryLoop()
    Do
        Await mainLoopRepeat()
    Loop
    Await secondaryLoop1 'It'll never be reached but I think I got what I want.
End Function
```

However it doesn't feel like elegant.

In any case, I want secondaryLoop and mainloop to be repeated as long as the program run.

I wonder if there is an elegant way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to run two infinite loops, I think the easiest way would be to make two asynchronous methods:

```
Private Async Function secondaryLoop() As Task
    Do
        CoinClass.assertCoinsNameOkay()
        Await CoinClass.checkMarketForAllCoinsAsync()
        CoinClass.assertCoinsNameOkay()
    Loop
End Function
Private Async Function mainLoop() As Task
    Do
        mainLoopRepeat()
    Loop
End Function
```

Then you can run them both as such:

```
Public Async Function finRepeatOrderingAsync() As Task
    basWindowFuncs.SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20()
    Await mainLoopRepeat()
    Await Task.WhenAll(mainLoop(), secondaryLoop())
End Function
```

Comment: Oh that's quite elegant